# Blackberry Application automatically minimizes upon launch

Tags: android, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I have made application in android and converted its apk to .bar file to upload on blackberry app World.But when i have uploaded on App world they tested it and gave me following issues.

**The application automatically minimizes upon launch.  The user must select the minimized application to gain access to the application.**

Is their any code which solve this matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working for couple of hours i  found that while moving from Activity1(Launcher Activity) -> Activity2 i have called finish().When i removed finish() then it does not minimizes upon launch.But i dont know why blackberry devices minimizes on finish().